# How to efficiently split a bash variable into two variables

Tags: bash

I have a variable $b which I want to split into two variables $startt and $finisht.

```
#!/bin/bash

b='08:10:00','11:12:00'

b=$(echo "$b" | tr -d "'")

IFS=',' read -r _ startt finisht _ <<<"$b"

echo "$startt"
echo "$finisht"
```

The following is the desired output. startt = 08:10:00 and finisht = 11:12:00. However when I run this script I only get 11:12:00. I want to split the variable as efficiently as possible. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the purpose of these `_` arguments in the `read` statement?

Comment: It's how one usually indicates unneeded fields; similar usage can be found in Python and Golang.

Comment: I'm more confused by the 'tr' usage, because the $b variable never actually has any single-quotes in it – they already get removed when parsing the assignment. Is this just a poor example and the original value actually comes from some other source (e.g. from command output)?

Comment: @user1686 By asking about `_`, I'm actually playing a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). It seems there are no unneeded fields.

Comment: Kamil, I got it. When I remove _ infront of startt and behind finisht I get the desired result so thanks.

Comment: Why not just use 2 commands to read first and second part.  I'm on my cell, so untested  but something like: startt=$(echo $b | cut -f1 -d,) ; finisht=$(echo $b |cut -f2 -d,)

Comment: read is bash build-in and therefore better choice before external cut (although cut is beginners friendly and <<< here strings not posix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
startt=${b%,*}  # cut off the comma and everything that follows
finisht=${b#*,} # cut off the comma and everything that precedes
```

```
>>>b='08:10:00','11:12:00'
>>>echo $b
08:10:00,11:12:00
>>>startt=${b%,*}
>>>finisht=${b#*,}
>>>echo $startt
08:10:00
>>>echo $finisht
11:12:00
```